# How do I tell ld to ignore a missing library?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I'd like to define a Makefile with implicit rules for a bunch of executables, some of which require linking against a custom-built library (let's call it `libedich.a`).

My problem is that I'd like to be able to build those executables that do not require `libedich.a` when the latter hasn't been built yet. If I simply add `-ledich` to the `LDLIBS` variable, I get errors when `libedich.a` doesn't exist:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledich
```

**How do I tell ld that it's okay to continue linking when a given library doesn't exist?**

Comment: You don't. You learn to use the autotools to generate the makefile based on the available resources.

Answer (score 6):

A common solution is to create a dummy archive so that GCC will find it. Since the executable doesn't need any symbols from the library, it won't error out. Like this,

```
# create an empty archive.
ar cru libedich.a
```

or even simpler,

```
echo '!<arch>' >libedich.a
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the downside of using one LDLIBS variable to hold all of the library dependencies and re-using it for every target, even though you know some targets only need a subset of the libraries.  You have several options:

- There are probably fancy IDE's and build tools out there that try to infer library dependencies from context, saving you from manually specifying them for each target.
- Switch to using shared libraries.
- Fix the target in your Makefile so that it depends on libedich.a (even if it doesn't need to).  This will work if you are building everything anyway and don't care what order the targets proceed in.
- Manually specify the library dependencies for each target in your Makefile.

The last option is my recommendation; it is more work, but eliminating the false dependencies in your Makefile will enable you to build (perhaps most of) your targets even if one of the dependencies is broken.  One convenient way to do this is with target-specific variables:

```
targetname::LDLIBS+=-ledich
```

You probably also want to be aware of `make --keep-going` (`make -k`)